# display .NET code error instead of HTTP 500

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I am using visual studio 2010 with vb.net. when an error occurs in code, instead of displaying the actual error, the browser shows HTTP 500. This is the problem with all browsers (chrome, internet explorer, firefox ). This never happened before. From yesterday, it happening this issue.

Comment: Does this happen on your local machine or only on the server?

Comment: it's happening on server .